# code not working when jquery version is changed

Tags: jquery

using an example code given on jsfiddle, that clicking on one checkbox unchecked all other checkboxes is working fine, but when i change the jquery version to 1.10.1, it doesn't work, any solution

```
 $(".chb").each(function(){
      $(this).change(function(){
        $(".chb").attr('checked',false);
        $(this).attr('checked',true);
     });
  });
```

here is the link

http://jsfiddle.net/44Zfv/

Comment: What version did you start with? I believe after 1.6 you should use `prop()`.

Comment: If you cannot change the jquery version, you can use the jquery migrate. http://blog.jquery.com/2013/05/08/jquery-migrate-1-2-1-released/. If you can change it, the answers help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're not changing the attribute but the property use jQuery's `prop` method instead. This will work with version 1.10+

```
$(".chb").each(function(){
    $(this).change(function(){
        $(".chb").prop('checked',false);
        $(this).prop('checked',true);
    });
});
```

**Difference between attribute and property**

http://www.w3.org/TR/SVGTiny12/attributeTable.html

Attributes are generally defined by the the HTML whereas properties are defined by the DOM. For some elements the property and the attribute reflect the same (e.g. the id of an element). A good way to show the DOM interaction is the following:

```
<input type="text" value="some value">
```

This element has two attributes (`type`, `text`). When the browser parses the document it will create an object for this specific element with the properties `type` and `value`. If you then write something in it, it will affect the elements `value` property. You can better see the difference when trying to retrieve the `value`:

```
input.getAttribute('value') // -> will return the inital value: "some value"
input.value // -> will return the object's value property (the text you've entered)
```

Comment: Could you explain the difference between a property and an attribute? I know I should be using prop(), but I don't quite understand the difference.

Answer (score 2):

The version is being switched from 1.5.2 to 1.10.  After jQuery 1.6 it is recommended to use `.prop()` in place of `.attr()`.

```
$(".chb").each(function(){
   $(this).change(function(){
       $(".chb").prop('checked',false);
       $(this).prop('checked',true);
   });
});
```

A better solution would be to use radio buttons, which will give you the desired behavior without any additional script.

```
<label><input type="radio" name="cb" class="chb" /> Radio1</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="cb" class="chb" /> Radio2</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="cb" class="chb" /> Radio3</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="cb" class="chb" /> Radio4</label>
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/44Zfv/292/

Answer (score 1):

Hi muzaffar try prop instead of attr

```
$(".chb").each(function()
    {
    $(this).change(function()
    {
    $(".chb").prop('checked',false);
    $(this).prop('checked',true);
    });
 });
```